# Someone please help me correct this error

Tags: texstudio

[image: image of my code and error]

I have attached the image of my code. Errors are also shown.
someone please help me correct those errors. I entered `\usepackage{ragged2e}` in the main .tex file [KTU M.Tech Thesis.tex]. Still these errors occur.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,justified]{KTUthesis}
\usepackage{KTUstyle}   \chaptertitle
\usepackage{pdftexcmds}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxmath,newtxtext}
\usepackage[cc]{titlepic}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\alternate
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{KTUbib}
\newcommand*{\formatauthor}[1]{%
    \textbf{\arabic{NAT@ctr}.#1}%
}
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,anchorcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=black,urlcolor=black,bookmarksnumbered=true,pdfview=FitB}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\addtocontents{toc}{{CONTENTS}\hfill{Page No.}\par}
\addtocontents{lot}{{No.}\hfill{Title}~\hfill{Page No.}\par}
\addtocontents{lof}{{No.}\hfill{Title}~\hfill{Page No.}\par}
\pdfbookmark[1]{TABLE OF CONTENTS}{table}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\chead{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg,.pdf,.mps,.png,.eps,.tif}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\fnum@figure}{Fig. \thefigure}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\include{Preface/titlepage}
\include{Preface/declaration}
\include{Preface/certificate}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\include{Preface/acknowledgement}
\include{Preface/abstract}
\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{}} \cleardoublepage \phantomsection
\cleardoublepage \phantomsection \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\include{Extras/LISTOFABBREVIATIONS}
\include{Extras/NOTATIONS}
\addtocontents{toc}{\def\protect\@chapapp{CHAPTER\ }}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Body/chapter1}
\include{Reference/biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Such screen shots of code are not really useful

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting some code. Unfortunately, it's not compilable. The files `KTUthesis.cls`, `KTUstyle.sty`, and `KTUbib.bst` (among others) appear to be proprietary. Are they available online somewhere? The code you've posted also loads files such as `LISTOFABBREVIATIONS.tex`, `NOTATIONS.tex`, `chapter1.tex`, and `biblio.tex`. We don't have them. What do expect us to d?

Comment: Can I attach files here? If so please tell me how to attach it. I have all those things with me. But in order to enter everything here the word limit doesnt allow me

Comment: No, you cannot attach your files. Make a MWE (see the link in Troy's comment). If files like `KTUthesis.cls` etc. are needed for the MWE give us a link to a *legal* download. If there is no legal download but if distribution is legally allowed make one using a file hoster. If distribution is not allowed ask the support for this class and packages.

Comment: Note: `\paragraph{}` is not needed to make a new paragraph. Omit it and  use an empty line only or use `\par`. `\paragraph{foo}` is intended for paragraphs with a catch phrase (something like an in-line heading) `foo`.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\paragraph{}` shouldn't be used directly after a `\justify` command or its environment, if you must use a `\paragraph{}`, then you can add a separating space like this to work:

```
\justify~
\paragraph{} Since it was easier to control ...
```

Besides, `\justify` is the default in LaTeX, so I expect that you only need the text Left justified: `flushleft`, `\raggedright`, Right justified: `flushright`, `\raggedleft`, or Centered: `center`, `\centering`, the first words for environments and the second ones for commands. Doing nothing of these translates to `\justify`.

**Edit:**

If you don't like the large space between two paragraphs, try adding to the preamble `\let\indent\parindent` and modify the text as this:

```
\justify\hspace{\indent}%
Since it was easier to control ...
```

is this what you want?

Comment: \justify~
\paragraph{} Since it was easier to control ...     This gave a large space between two paragraphs. usually when I write tex files justification was default. but inn this case it is not happening. everything is centred. I  couldnt find why it  is so.

Comment: That is the very same reason people here are asking for a MWE including your class and packages used. The class file you're using seems to modify the default behavior. No one can predict what is wrong without your actual MWE.

Comment: I have added the code. please check through

Comment: Still as the comment by @Mico above, the `KTUthesis.cls` file and others are missing,  where can we find these?